# Randomly choose between a selection of if statements(ACF Fields)

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a few ACF fields displaying in a template. The fields are true/false and are checked or not depending on the page. These fields are not part of a repeater and unfortunately, it's not viable to switch the fields over to repeaters at this moment.

Here are how the fields are displayed currently:

```
    $html .= '<div class="icons">'; 
if( get_field('restaurants') ):
 $html .= '<div class="icon_group"><span class="icon"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/ico-restaurant.png" alt="ico restaurant"</span><span class="title">Restaurants</span></div>';
endif;

if( get_field('beach') ):
 $html .= '<div class="icon_group"><span class="icon"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/ico-beach.png" alt="ico beach" </span><span class="title">Beach</span></div>';
endif;

if( get_field('chapel') ):
 $html .= '<div class="icon_group"><span class="icon"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/ico-chapel.png" alt="ico chapel"</span><span class="title">Chapel</span></div>';
endif;

if( get_field('day_spa') ):
 $html .= '<div class="icon_group"><span class="icon"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/ico-day-spa.png" alt="ico day spa"</span><span class="title">Day Spa</span></div>';
endif;
```

I would like to see which if statements return a value/exist and then randomly choose 3 of them to display.

How would I go about this?

I've tried to randomise the fields and display them but the problem I've gotten is sometimes a non-active field is displayed and therefore leaves a gap on the front-end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build an array of HTML snippets for the active fields, and then take a random selection from that array:

```
$divs = array();
if( get_field('restaurants') ):
 $divs[] = '<div class="icon_group"><span class="icon"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/ico-restaurant.png" alt="ico restaurant"</span><span class="title">Restaurants</span></div>';
endif;

if( get_field('beach') ):
 $divs[] = '<div class="icon_group"><span class="icon"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/ico-beach.png" alt="ico beach" </span><span class="title">Beach</span></div>';
endif;

if( get_field('chapel') ):
 $divs[] = '<div class="icon_group"><span class="icon"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/ico-chapel.png" alt="ico chapel"</span><span class="title">Chapel</span></div>';
endif;

if( get_field('day_spa') ):
 $divs[] = '<div class="icon_group"><span class="icon"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/ico-day-spa.png" alt="ico day spa"</span><span class="title">Day Spa</span></div>';
endif;

shuffle($divs);
for ($i = 0; $i < min(3, count($divs)); $i++) {
    echo $divs[$i];
}
```